# finding and replacing the same character which appears multiple times at the end of the string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a requirement where I need to replace a special character like `","` or `";"` which occurs mulitple times at the end of the string.

suppose I have a string

```
String1="a,b,c,d,,";
```

I should be able to remove all the commas which appear at the end of the of `'d'.`

If the occurrance is only once I can replace it using the follwing code.

```
String1= String1.substring(String1.length,String1.length-1);
```

Now if we have more than one comma appearing at the end how do I replace all?

Comment: I f I were to remove duplicate values in the middle of a string.How would I do it.If I hava a String like String1="a,b,,,c".I want to replace the commas occuring in the middle with a single comma.How would I do it.

Answer (score 5):

You should use a regex...

```
str = str.replace(/,+$/, "");
```

Comment: I used the above expression and is working as expected.Just wanted to know how this works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$string="a,b,c,d,,";
echo trim(preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i", ",", $string), ',');
?>
```

Comment: I never knew JavaScript was, in fact, PHP.